# push property value to object, store and accumulate, then randomly select 2

Tags: javascript

Ok, can't get this. I'm trying to push an object property key:value' to an empty object, store it in a variable, then next call retrieve that updated object, and add a new key:value pair to it, then finally grab 2 different random values from the created object. Here's what I've tried:

```
var obj {};
var storedObject;
var randomResponse1 = pickRand1(obj);
var randomResponse2 = pickRand1(obj);

  //first visit to server
if (event.reply == "true") {
    obj.1 = 'one';
    obj = storedObject;
 }

 //second visit to server
 if (event.reply == "true") {
    obj.2 = 'two';
    obj = storedObject;
  }


 //third visit to server
 if (event.reply == "true") {
    obj.3 = 'three';
    obj = storedObject;
  }


 //fourth visit to server
 if (event.reply == "true") {
    obj.4 = 'four';
    obj = storedObject;
  }


 //final visit to server
 if (event.reply == "true") {
    alert(randomResponse1); //it only seems to grab last value
    alert(randomResponse2); //also, does this have a chance of 
                                    //being the same random result?
  }


  function pickRand1(obj) {
    var result;
    var count = 0;
      for (var prop in obj)
      if (Math.random() < 1/++count)
         result = obj[prop];
    return result;
  }
```

Comment: This is not even valid JavaScript syntax.

Comment: Please provide working code to illustrate the problem. There are multiple problems, both syntactical and logical, with the posted code. If you can't get it to run, ask about the errors you encounter.

Comment: Yeah, will do. Sorry about that. I'm not too fluent and rushed through it just to grasp it conceptually. I'll update it as soon as I get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is setting a property like `obj.1 = 'one'` (Not to mention that it's not a valid syntax), then assigning `storedObject` to `obj` which will make it exactly the same as `storedObject` discarding any previous changes to `obj`.

What you need instead is something like this:

```
obj[1] = 'one'
obj = Object.assign(obj, storedObject)
```

This will merge the `obj` content with `storedObject` content and save the result to `obj`.

PS: The declaration needs to be like this `var obj = {}`. Make sure you fix all syntax mistakes before you look for functional issues.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say for sure what the issue is without being able to test the code, but I found a few things that might be causing your problem.

First, dot-notation with Javascript object only works with valid identifiers, which cannot begin with a digit. I switched your code to use bracket-notation, which does work with all valid strings, e.g. `obj["1"]`.

I also edited your random function. In your original function, it seems like you have a 1/1 chance to choose the first key, 1/2 to choose the second, and so on. The new function works by converting `obj`'s to an array, and then choosing a random index for the array, which in turn will give us a random key. Also, as Derek kindly mentioned, you were missing the brackets on your original for-loop :)

Finally, to answer your question in the comments: yes, it's possible that both calls to the random function will return the same object (but that can be easily changed).

I attached a code snippet with my edits below. Let me know if this helps!

Note: I'm not sure what frameworks/libraries/etc you're using with this code, but given the way right now, all of your if-statements will run on the first visit to the server. I think you need to implement some sort of queuing-system to ensure that the if-statements will run on separate visits.

```js
let obj {};
let storedObject;
let randomResponse1 = pickRand1(obj);
let randomResponse2 = pickRand1(obj);

  //first visit to server
if (event.reply == "true") {
    obj["1"] = 'one';
    obj = storedObject;
 }

 //second visit to server
 if (event.reply == "true") {
    obj["2"] = 'two';
    obj = storedObject;
  }


 //third visit to server
 if (event.reply == "true") {
    obj["3"] = 'three';
    obj = storedObject;
  }


 //fourth visit to server
 if (event.reply == "true") {
    obj["4"] = 'four';
    obj = storedObject;
  }


 //final visit to server
 if (event.reply == "true") {
    alert(randomResponse1); //it only seems to grab last value
    alert(randomResponse2); //also, does this have a chance of 
                                    //being the same random result?
  }


  function pickRand1(obj) {
    let keys = Object.keys(obj);
    let numKeys = keys.length;
    let randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * numKeys);
    let randomKey = keys[randomIndex];
    let result = obj[randomKey];
    return result;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

it wasn't super clear what you are trying to achieve here but bear in mind;

- don't test `if( val == "true" )` instead, if your value evaluates to a boolean, just test `if( val )`
- your `obj` variable is in the global scope, you don't have to keep saving it, you can just add properties to it
- if you want your two random properties to be different from each other, remove the first before selecting the second.

```js
var event = {
  reply: true
};

var obj = {};

//first visit to server
if (event.reply) {
  obj.a = 'one';
}

//second visit to server
if (event.reply) {
  obj.b = 'two';
}


//third visit to server
if (event.reply) {
  obj.c = 'three';
}


//fourth visit to server
if (event.reply) {
  obj.d = 'four';
}

//fifth visit to server
if (event.reply) {
  var arr = Object.keys(obj);
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  var key = arr[i];
  console.log(obj[key])
  delete obj[key];
  arr = Object.keys(obj);
  i = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
  key = arr[i];
  console.log(obj[key]);
}
```